# How can I swtich to different Google Account in ADdMob?

Tags: admob

I have two google accounts. One is my personal use, the other is for my app. If I log in both and open AdMob console, it always shows my personal account one. I can't find a way to switch to another account. In some Google apps like Gmail, I am able to do that by clicking right top profile image. But in AdMob, I cannot. The only solution is that I have to log out my personal account, it is annoying. Is there a way to switch accounts without logging out the other?

Comment: this is very annoying and i could not find a solution

Comment: Still no solution, but I found browsers can solve this problem. If using Firefox, I can use container. If using Chrome, I can use different profiles. But for me Firefox is better because it uses same bookmarks cross different containers. While with Chrome, it is completely different user session.

Answer (score 0):

I seems to work fine for other Google products, but with Admob it continues to switch back to the personal account.

My solution is to use another browser for AdMob :(

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue and I agree, this is very annoying. Perhaps you can try workaround: **send invitation to your another google account and accept it, then login with a new account as a manager or administrator.**
Not sure that it 100% helps, but in my case I'm able to login.
Not clear why Admob developers can't fix so easy bug.

Answer (score -1):

Go to google.com, left click on your profile photo in the top right of the browser, and then click 'Sign Out'. Proceed to AdMob website and try signing up again - this time you will be asked to sign in with a desired account instead of one being selected for you.

Comment: The question specifically states they do not want to sign out.